# Traducir cadena de texto en javascript que retornar objetos de un json

Tags: javascript, json

Este es mi json
los objetos "main" y "description" que me retorna al consumir la api como se ve  estan en ingles y lo que quiero es transformar estos campos al español una vez que me los retorne desde el json

weather": [

```
{
    "id": 741,
    "main": "Fog",
    "description": "fog",
    "icon": "50d"
}
```

lo que tengo de codigo hasta ahora es esto, me retorna bien los objetos del json, pero no puedo transformalos al español.

```js
function mostrar() {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var apikey = "key del sitio";
        var description;
        var main;
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=3868626&units=metric&APPID=" + apikey,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

            description = data.weather[0].description;
            main = data.weather[0].main;

                $("#txtClima").val(main);
                $("#txtClimaDescripcion").val(description);

                },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });            
    });
}
```

Comment: ¿No puedes porque no sabes la traducción? ¿O no puedes porque ni siquiera lo intentas? Para traducir cualquier cadena has de tener ya armado un diccionario de traducción. La API de [`openweathermap`](https://openweathermap.org) acepta un parámetro para idioma, que aplica sólo para el campo `description`. Por favor revisa la [documentación](https://openweathermap.org/current#multi) de la misma. Saludos

Comment: Por algo lo publico, porque he intentado de varias formas y nada, tambien he leido la documentacion, solo los devuelve en ingles.

Comment: Pero en tu cadena de solicitud no se ve que agregues el parámetro de idioma, debería ser: `url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=3868626&units=metric&lang=es&APPID=" + apikey`. Te falta el parametro `lang=es`. Y recuerda que sólo el campo `description` estará en castellano. Saludos

Comment: Me sirve, pero de igual manera, quiero encontrar la manera de traducir el main 
ya que si bien traduce el campo description no lo hace de manera "correcta". Saludos.

Comment: En ese caso, tienes muchas opciones, una forma es crear un diccionario con la palabra en inglés y su correspondencia en español. Por ejemplo, un objeto: `const mainDict = {Fog: 'Niebla', Clear: 'Despejado', ... }`. Luego puedes usar dicho objeto así: `let main = mainDict[data.weather[0].main];`. Así, cuando `data.weather[0].main` sea por ejemplo `Fog`, entonces estarás invocando el valor de `mainDict['Fog']` que corresponde a `'Niebla'`, y es esto último lo que se guardará en tu variable `main`. La verdad es que existen muchas otras formas, pero esta es la que se me ocurre. Saludos

Comment: Si ya esta desarrollado simplemente lo implementas, puedes usar https://github.com/ngx-translate/core.

Comment: sabes que implemento lo que me dices pero no se donde ubicarlo dentro del codigo o yo estoy haciendo algo mal, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Para empezar, ¿usas Angular en el frontend? Porque de lo contrario te será un poco difícil implementar esa solución que te dieron, ya que es pensada para ser usada en Angular.

Comment: Wut es cierto mauricio, creo que esta usando javascript vanilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma muy básica de lograr lo que te propones es crear un diccionario que contenga la traducción de las palabras que vienen desde la API que consumes.

La lista completa de palabras que usa [OpenWeatherMap](https://openweathermap.org), la consigues en: [Weather Conditions Codes](https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions).

La traducción de la misma es tu tarea, yo aquí implementaré un ejemplo muy sencillo.

Creamos un diccionario para las palabras del campo `main` y otro para las palabras del campo `description`:

```js
const mainDict = {
  Thunderstorm: 'Tormenta',
  Drizzle: 'Llovizna',
  Rain: 'Lluvia',
  Snow: 'Nieve',
  Mist: 'Bruma',
  Smoke: 'Humo',
  Haze: 'Neblina',
  Dust: 'Polvo',
  Fog: 'Niebla',
  Sand: 'Arena',
  Ash: 'Ceniza',
  Squall: 'Chubasco',
  Tornado: 'Tornado',
  Clear: 'Despejado',
  Clouds: 'Nubes'
}
```

Ya tenemos listo el diccionario para el campo `main`, ahora veamos cómo podemos usarlo.

No voy a entrar en detalles de cómo implementarlo de forma *mantenible*, simplemente lo usaré directamente en la función `mostrar()`.

```js
function mostrar() {
  //declaramos nuestro diccionario
  const mainDict = {
    Thunderstorm: 'Tormenta',
    Drizzle: 'Llovizna',
    Rain: 'Lluvia',
    Snow: 'Nieve',
    Mist: 'Bruma',
    Smoke: 'Humo',
    Haze: 'Neblina',
    Dust: 'Polvo',
    Fog: 'Niebla',
    Sand: 'Arena',
    Ash: 'Ceniza',
    Squall: 'Chubasco',
    Tornado: 'Tornado',
    Clear: 'Despejado',
    Clouds: 'Nubes'
  }
  // aqui declaramos el diccionario para el campo description (es tarea asignada)
  const descDict = { ... }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    var apikey = "key del sitio";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=3868626&units=metric&APPID=" + apikey,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        let description = descDict[data.weather[0].description];
        let main = mainDict[data.weather[0].main];
        $("#txtClima").val(main);
        $("#txtClimaDescripcion").val(description);
      },
      error: function (errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
      }
    });            
  });
}
```

Esto sería un ejemplo de lo que se almacena en las variables `description` y `main`, usando tus coordenadas:

```js
const mainDict = {
  Thunderstorm: 'Tormenta',
  Drizzle: 'Llovizna',
  Rain: 'Lluvia',
  Snow: 'Nieve',
  Mist: 'Bruma',
  Smoke: 'Humo',
  Haze: 'Neblina',
  Dust: 'Polvo',
  Fog: 'Niebla',
  Sand: 'Arena',
  Ash: 'Ceniza',
  Squall: 'Chubasco',
  Tornado: 'Tornado',
  Clear: 'Despejado',
  Clouds: 'Nubes'
}

const data = {
  "coord": {"lon":-71.63,"lat":-33.04},
  "weather":[
     {"id":701,"main":"Mist","description":"niebla","icon":"50d"},
     {"id":721,"main":"Haze","description":"niebla","icon":"50d"}
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{"temp":12.7,"pressure":1014,"humidity":100,"temp_min":11,"temp_max":14},
   "visibility":4000,
   "wind":{"speed":3.6,"deg":330},
   "clouds":{"all":90},
   "dt":1570826764,
   "sys":{"type":1,"id":8498,"message":0.0062,"country":"CL","sunrise":1570788651,"sunset":1570834526},
   "timezone":-10800,
   "id":3868626,
   "name":"Valparaiso",
   "cod":200
 }
 
let main1 = mainDict[data.weather[0].main];
let main2 = mainDict[data.weather[1].main];

console.log('Dato original: ', data.weather[0].main);
console.log('Dato traducido: ', main1);

console.log('Dato original: ', data.weather[1].main);
console.log('Dato traducido: ', main2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas y te ayude a resolver el problema.

**Nota**

La traducción es propia y no necesariamente es exacta.